# What's the recommended way of doing a complete update (replace) on a document?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

We're currently in the process of creating a service with a simple CRUD api using typescript and mongoose.
We have a PUT endpoint for updating documents.

### What we want

1. No partial update of document properties, the document should be overwritten, so that optional properties are deleted if they are not provided
   Example:
   Existing document:
   `{ title: 'Test', optionalProperty: 123 }`
   `PUT { title: 'Test2' }` deletes `optionalProperty`
2. Timestamps are preserverd, so `createdAt` keeps the date of the initial creation of document and `updatedAt` has the date of the last successful PUT
3. The version key `__v` is getting incremented on every PUT
4. Discriminators are updated, if discriminator key changes
5. If possible, the operation should be atomic (no `find` and then `save`)

### What we tried

- `findByIdAndUpdate` with options `new: true, overwriteDiscriminatorKey: true, overwrite: true, runValidators: true`

  - Works ok, but `createdAt` timestamp is updated
  - Version key `__v` is removed on first update

    - We tried to manually increment the version key with `$inc: {__v: 1}`, but was ignored, unless you remove `overwrite: true` option
  - If we set `timestamp: {createdAt: false, updatedAt: true}`, createdAt will be removed (typescript types don't support this, casting was necessary)
  - If we set `createdAt` to `immutable`, createdAt was still updated
- `findOneAndReplace`

  - Same as `findByIdAndUpdate`, `createdAt` timestamp is also updated (also with latest mongoose version)

#### Other findings

Manually creating a middleware for version key updates (described [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey)) doesn't work with typescript, because update is readyonly.